# ArcGIS Pro Properties for All Symbols

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS/ArcMap Desktop one can right-click in the layer symbology window and choose to modify properties for all or selected symbol classes. In ArcGIS Pro I can't find a similar workflow. What am I missing?

For instance I have a single polygon layer, symbolized with graduated colors. I would like to eliminate the outline from all the symbol classes. I can do this one class at a time, but this is tedious. I can select all symbols in the usual ctrl+click manner, but can't find an option to modify symbols for all selected classes. I fail to find a solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from `Symbology` tab, just click in `More` to access to `Format all symbols`:

[image]

If you want to format just some symbols, select them (you can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> to select several items), right click and select `Format symbol(s)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the symbology for all the features of the feature class/shapefile? The only way I can find to adjust symbology is to just double click on the symbol, leading you into the symbology window. I think there's graduated colors option there.

Comment: Yes, that's how you would modify an individual symbol. However, I want to change properties for several symbols at once.

Comment: @tharen I found that you can change color fill simultaneously but couldn't find an option to change the outline properties simultaneously. But honestly, I don't even know how you can go about to change the outlines of multiple features in one sitting in ArcMap. Could you tell me how to do that please? I can change the colors but not the outline. Do you do it in the symbology tab of the properties? Thanks